# Best practice in specifying the correct spring-instrument agent jar

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, aspectj, proxy-classes

I am planning to use AspectJ's loadtime weaving feature for proxying in a Spring based web application. The three things (AFAIK) that are needed to get this working are:

1. Set the proxying mode to "`aspectj`" (as opposed to "`proxy`")
2. Add the `spring-aspects` and the `aspectjweaver` to the classpath
3. Add the `spring-instrument` agent to the VM startup

My question was on the best practice on how to achieve #3. My causes of concern are:

1. Since this is needed at application startup, I can't have it point to the spring-instrument jar in the `WEB-INF/lib` location of my webapp. I was thinking of having a static `spring-instrument` jar sitting in my `CATALINA_HOME/lib` that can be directly referred to.
2. As the web application progresses, it might be the case that the spring version may be upgraded and we may forget to upgrade the version of the jar in `CATALINA_HOME/lib`.
3. Many different applications may be using the same `CATALINA_HOME` and it is not always possible to have everyone upgrade the `spring-instrument` jar in lock-step fashion.

Since this problem seems to be like a generic one, I wanted to know from others how they address this concern.

Thanks!

Comment: Depending on your container you don't need the instrumentation and a single `<context:load-time-weaver />` is enough. This is supported on tomcat, jboss, web logic and web sphere. For it to work on tomcat you need a recent version.

Comment: Taking a specific example of Tomcat, I guess you still need TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader in `CATALINA_HOME/lib` for which we would still need to add the appropriate version of `spring.instrument.tomcat jar`, right?

Comment: No you don't need that.

Comment: Maybe I am not using the right version of tomcat. Can you name a version of tomcat where this works as you suggest? Thanks!

Comment: You need a fairly recent version of Spring 4.0 or up and a recent version of tomcat I believe version 8.

Comment: You are right! Working with tomcat 8 (I tried with 8.0.3), and I was able to get it to work correctly. If you add an answer, I can mark that as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the container you don't need the `spring-instrumentation.jar`. A single `<context:load-time-weaver />` in your configuration is enough.

You will need a recent version of Tomcat (version 8), Jetty, WebSphere, Weblogic or JBoss.